# Function call works only for first call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a spell checker, where it shows a drop-down menu with suggestions beside every incorrect word. Whenever I click ANY drop-down list to select the suggested correct word,it changes only for the FIRST incorrect word. However, I wanted to change each incorrect word by clicking each drop-down menu suggestion separately just like typical spell checker works.

I think I should bring some changes in javascript function call on this line,

```
echo "<select onChange='changeFunc()'  id='selectCorrct' style='border:none; width:15px; '  required>
                        <option value=''></option>";
```

The code-sample  is below:

```
echo "<font id='change_word'  style=\"color:red; font-size:23px;\">$input</font>";
                echo "<select onChange='changeFunc()'  id='selectCorrct' style='border:none; width:15px; '  required>
                        <option value=''></option>";

                $name='';
                if(sizeof($temp_word_soundex) <= 5){
                    for($k=0;$k<sizeof($temp_word_soundex);$k++){

                        $specific = explode(" ",$temp_word_soundex[$k]);
                        $name = $name.$specific[1]." | ";
                        echo "<option value='$specific[1]' style=\"color:black; font-size:23px;\">$specific[1]</option>";   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for($k=0;$k<5;$k++){
                        $specific = explode(" ",$temp_word_soundex[$k]);
                        $name = $name.$specific[1]." | ";
                        echo "<option value='$specific[1]'   style=\"color:black; font-size:23px;\">$specific[1]</option>";     
                    }
                }

                echo "</select>";
```

//////////// JAVASCRIPT CODE BELOW /////////

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeFunc(){
        var a = document.getElementById('selectCorrct').value;
        document.getElementById('change_word').innerHTML=a;
        document.getElementById('change_word').style.color='green';


    }

</script>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, `getElementById()` will only return the first element with the ID. Use a class and loop over all of them.

Comment: it's also suggested to create a non dynamic static html with js file, manually create 2-3 drop downs next to each word and solve any issues. Once you get it right then replicate the solution in php. Solving problems in isolation and simplest form can help you.